# Laravel Relationships with a table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently struggling as I am quite new to the relationships in Laravel.
I have a model Products, who is made of one model Material.
Material can be used in several Products.

I have a table called product_material to link them.

What I have so far 
In Product

```
public function material()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Material::class, '');
}
```

In Material

```
 public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_material');
}
```

But this give me an error saying that I dont have any product_id in my material table.

But : My material isnt suppose to have a product_id as when it is created it is not linked to anything and it can be use in several products

Edit: DB structure

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->string('code',45);
});

Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->string('code',45);
});
Schema::create('product_material', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('material_id');
    });
```

Comment: Can you share database structure?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong relations, and wrong schema

If 1 Product Has Several Materials then it should be ( **1 to Many** )

now One Material has Many Product too so relation should be

> In short One Product has multiple materials and one material has
>   several product so at last relation should be :

**MANY TO MANY and use BELONG TO MANY**

---

Answer (score 1):

If you’re *certain* a Product will only ever have one Material, then this would be a belongs to/has many relationship. A Product would have one Material, but Material could have many products.

You’d therefore not need a pivot table; your `products` table would have a `material_id` which would be a foreign key to the `materials` table.

```php
class Material extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function material()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Material::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id','product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified empty string here.

```
public function material()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Material::class);
}
```

If you want to not specified any key like `product_id` then you specified that key as extra parameters that points to some id anohter table.

like this

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

For mote [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have any foreign key. Just a table being a link beween the two models

Comment: okay, I am also told that how you can specified another key if you don't specified any foreign key, by default laravel take foreign key automatically as (`_id`) convention. If you dont have column according that convention than you can specified in relationship's method.

Answer (score 0):

Model `Product.php`

```
public function materials()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Material::class, 'product_material');
}
```

You can directly get `materials` from your `product`  table

Model `ProductMaterial.php`

```
public function material()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Material::class, 'material_id');
}

public function product()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

Refer: [Laravel Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)